# communication between smartphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, connection, smartphone

how can I communicate with another smartphone per example in a game?
I'm developing in objective-c, I need to pass/receive informations about positions of some elements on the screen, but I've not ideas of how i can do this, can you give me some tips? Do i need a physical server with a socket open? and how can i manage the connection?

Thanks for any help.
Jonathan.

Comment: Did one of the answers help? If so, please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Look into the peer-to-peer methods of [GameKit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html). It's designed for multiple devices to communicate with each other. iOS only.

Answer (score 0):

One phone can't readily programmatically talk directly to another phone.  Well, you might be able to get phone A to send an email or SMS to phone B, but then phone B's app won't be able to act on the notification.  (Since you mention obj-C I assume you're using iOS)

So you'll likely have to have a central server help out.  Assuming apps running on both phones.  Phone A can make an http request to the server; while phone B polls for a possible response.  It can use a comet-like technique to reduce polling overhead.